# DRY me. Rails code:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I have several of this, where the only thing that differs is if its a text_field or a password_field etc etc etc. 
I'd like to pass this as a parameter to the render, like :as => :password_field for example.
And I don't wan't to do a case compare, the value passed in the :as is the value of the field. Is this possible ?

```
.text{:class => form.object.errors[field].any? ? "error" : nil}
  = form.label field
  -if defined? value
    = form.text_field field, :value => value
  -else
    = form.password_field field 
  -if defined? hint
    %p#hint= hint
  = render 'shared/error_messages', :object => form.object, :field
```

```
.text{:class => form.object.errors[field].any? ? "error" : nil}
  = form.label field
  -if defined? value
    = form.text_area field, :value => value
  -else
    = form.text_area field 
  -if defined? hint
    %p#hint= hint
  = render 'shared/error_messages', :object => form.object, :field => field
```

Answer is the one below, with some fixes:

```
-# expects form, field_name, field_type, value and hint variables to be passed
.text{:class => form.object.errors[field_name].any? ? "error" : nil}
  = form.label field_name
  - if defined?(value)
    = form.send(field_type, field_name, :value => value)
  - else
    /= form.send(:field_type, field_name)   
    = form.send(field_type, field_name)   
  -if defined? hint
    %p#hint= hint
  = render 'shared/error_messages', :object => form.object, :field => field_name
```

Usage:
`= render 'shared/form_field', :form => f, :field_name => :email, :field_type => :text_field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a partial called `shared/form_field.html.haml`

```
- # expects form, field_name, field_type, value and hint variables to be passed
.text{:class => form.object.errors[field_name].any? ? "error" : nil}
  = form.label field_name
  - if defined?(value)
    = form.send(:field_type, field_name, :value => value)
  - else
    = form.send(:field_type, field_name)
  -if defined? hint
    %p#hint= hint
  = render 'shared/error_messages', :object => form.object, :field => field_name
```

You can invoke the partial as

```
- form_for :user do |form|
 = render 'shared/form_field', :locals => {:form => form, 
                        :field_name => :login, :field_type => :text_field}
```

Comment: Yes, sir, enough to come up with the answer

Comment: It seems that form.send(:field_type, field_name) is the same as  form.send(:field_type, field_name, :value => value) on both cases it prints the value if value is not null, any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you're after this:

```
render :partial => 'user/login_errors', :locals => { :field => :first_name, :value => @user.first_name, :form => form }
```

You use the locals hash to pass in any number of variables. In your case, the variables in your code snippet were `form`, `field`, and `value`. The keys in the hash determine what the variable will be referenced as in the partial, and the values in the hash determine the variable values.